# How to use group by with several joins

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I have a query that is reaching my goal but it is not using group by. All the examples of group by i see on the internet are either too simple or i don't understand them. Can someone "convert" my code to using a group by?

```
            var registos = from reg in dcxBaseDados.RegistoConsumo
                       join utl in dcxBaseDados.Utilizadores on reg.IdUser equals utl.ID
                       join car in dcxBaseDados.Veiculos on reg.IdVeiculo equals car.ID
                       where (utilizador == 0 || reg.Utilizadores.ID == utilizador) && (matricula == "" || reg.Matricula == matricula) && (destino == "" || reg.Destino == destino) && (reg.Data >= dataInicio && reg.Data <= dataFinal)
                       select new
                       {
                           Data = reg.Data,
                           Matricula = reg.Matricula,
                           nrMecano = adicionarZeros((int)utl.NrMecanografico),
                           Nome = utl.Nome,
                           Km = reg.Km,
                           TotalAntesAbastecer = reg.TotalAntesAbastecer,
                           Categoria = car.Categoria,
                           Destino = reg.Destino,
                           Cor = car.Cor,
                           Litros = reg.Consumo_Lote.Select(lote => lote.Litros).Sum()
                       };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = registos;
```

[image]

*Variables are in Portuguese, if you need me to translate them for better understanding ask please.*

**EDIT (just some information so you don't think this is for school =))**
The code above does do what i want. But here is some context: This is not a school work. I am a 12º grade course in programming. I am now doing an internship in a company and one of the employes was helping me do this. He showed me this way when i asked him how to do a sum of the litros. He said that it was more correct to use group by, but since he works with vb.net and does not know how to do it in c# "out of his heart" and he said he his tired, he did not investigate more on how to do it. Since i am learning i want to find how the best possible way, **that is why i am asking this question. My code works, but since there is a better way i would like to know how.**

Comment: By what do you want to group them?

Comment: Don't understand the question. I want to show all the info inside the {} and in litros i want to show the sum of lote.Litros.

Comment: GroupBy works like this: 
1 a, 1 b, 2 c, 3 d, 2 c, 4 e, 5 d, 5 c, 5 b, 
GroupByLetter => c 2, c 2, c 5,      b 1, b 5,     d 3, d 5,    a 1,     e 4
it makes groups based on column values, I don't think that is what you want to do.

Comment: Now I understand, you want to replace your code by code using Group By.

Comment: Yes, that is it. But the examples i find are either too simple or i don't understand them. In VB.net is easy but in c# is much more "complex"

Comment: What's the problem with your query? It looks ok to me, should return the correct sum of Litros, no?

Comment: @meme please show us the VB.Net code that does what you want, then we can help you translate.

Comment: @IvanStoev I guess it's homework or some schooltask. "Show how this can be done with GroupBy"

Comment: Ill update the question 1 sec.

Comment: @Master117 The problem is though that (as you mentioned in your first comment) in order to do `GroupBy`, you need to know **By**, which OP didn't provide.

Comment: @IvanStoev thats why I wanted to see the VB.Net version.

Comment: There is no VB version. I added the database to better explain.

Comment: @meme If you can do something with or without `GroupBy`, the later is always better. Your code is just fine.

Comment: Its just an optimization reason. The way i am using is slower than a group by. Hence why i made the question.